# Initializing nested void pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

I have a struct that stores some data as a void pointer and a integer like this:

```
 struct container
 {
   int size;
   void* data;
 };
```

Now I have a second struct:

```
 struct date
 {
   int day;
   int year;
 };
```

And I have function that initialized such a container and returns it:

```
struct container get_container()
{
    struct container d = { .data=  {(struct date){.day = 1, .year = 2}, (struct date){.day = 4, .year = 5}}, .size = 2};
    return d;
}
```

But when I compile the code the compiler complains that types mismatch:

```
test.c:19:34: error: initializing 'void *' with an expression of incompatible type 'struct date'
        struct container d = { .data=  {(struct date){.day = 1, .year = 2}, (struct date){.day = 4, .year = 5}}, .size = 2};
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Even if I a void* cast to the init it doesn't work. Is there any way to do this, without using malloc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the initializer to compile, you will need to use compound literals (which were also added to C99 alongside the designated initializers you are using):

```
struct container d =
{
    .data = (struct date[]){ { .day = 1, .year = 2 }, { .day = 4, .year = 5 } },
    .size = 2
};
```

It is harder to determine whether returning a copy of that structure is 'safe'.  The issue is whether the array of dates continues to exist after the function returns (it doesn't) and whether it can safely be modified by the code that gets a pointer returned (it can).

*Thanks to [2501](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4082723/2501) for pointing out where to look in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26511027/initializing-nested-void-pointer/26511291#comment41653274_26511291).*

> #### ISO/IEC 9899:2011
>
> §6.2.4 **Storage durations of objects**, ¶6 *[discussing automatic duration objects]* …If an initialization is specified for the object, it is performed each time the declaration or compound literal is reached in the execution of the block; otherwise, the value becomes indeterminate each time the declaration is reached.
>
> §6.5.2.5 **Compound literals**, ¶5 The value of the compound literal is that of an unnamed object initialized by the initializer list. If the compound literal occurs outside the body of a function, the object has static storage duration; otherwise, it has automatic storage duration associated with
>   the enclosing block.

So, to return the pointer to the array of dates, you need to use explicit memory allocation (`malloc()` et al).  Presumably, you will have other containers holding different types of data than just `struct date` — otherwise, you're abusing `void *` (use `struct date *` instead, or consider the merits of a flexible array member).

Comment: Thanks, that compiles. But I understood the other answer correctly the array allocation will happen on the stack and if I dereference that pointer I will point to nothing useful once the frame is popped?

Comment: I addressed that in my addition to the answer.  The return value is a copy of the `struct container`, so there's no problem with that, per se.  The issue is 'what does the pointer point at' — and the answer is 'an anonymous array literal'.  I'd need to look at the standard rather carefully to know whether that array literal is read-only or modifiable.  I believe its duration will be 'life of program' but that too should be checked.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Compound literals have automatic duration. They are gone on return. It would be great if you could point that out.

Comment: @2501: yes, I agree.  ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.2.4 Storage durations of objects, §6 (discussing automatic duration objects) _…If an
initialization is specified for the object, it is performed each time the declaration or
compound literal is reached in the execution of the block; otherwise, the value becomes
indeterminate each time the declaration is reached._

Comment: I think this is more relevant: *6.5.2.5. p5: The value of the compound literal is that of an unnamed object initialized by the
initializer list. If the compound literal occurs outside the body of a function, the object
has static storage duration; otherwise, it has automatic storage duration associated with
the enclosing block.*

Comment: @2501: indeed, that is also relevant — it looks suspiciously like two parts of the standard saying the same thing (at least it _is_ self-consistent!).  I had not gone ahead to look at §6.5.2.5 _Compound literals_ since §6.2.4 seemed to cover the point and standards usually avoid repetition.

Answer (score 2):

You're attempting to assign a struct value to a void pointer, which wont work. You need to take the address of your struct and assign `data` to that instead. This means you need to use malloc. If you didn't use malloc you'd be taking a pointer to a local stack variable, which "disappears" once the function it was declared in ends and its frame is popped from the stack. At that point your pointer would not be pointing to what you expect.